# Does a function need to have a parameter underlying all inputs to be totally differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following function 
$$e(p_x,p_y,\bar{U}) = p_x a(p_x,p_y,\bar{U}) + p_y b(p_x,p_y,\bar{U})$$

Can I take the total derivative of this? I am confused about the criteria for something to be totally differentiable.

**My Question:**

1. Is the function above totally differentiable (assuming the functions chosen aren't weird or kinky or something)?
2. How can I tell if something is totally differentiable?

Comment: You have an unclosed $($. The total derivative WRT what?

Comment: @GFauxPas Thanks!